# local keymap in mode-line doesn't work in terminal

Tags: osx, keymap, mode-line, terminal-emacs, mouse

I'm having trouble with getting local keymap:s to work in the mode-line, but only in terminals (with `xterm-mouse-mode` enabled).

This applies to both the standard mode-line entries (like `mode-line-toggle-read-only`) and entries I manually add.

For example, the following work in a GUI Emacs (tested on the NS port on macOS), but not in an Emacs running in a terminal. (When clicking on the `PRESSME` text in the mode-line, the message `I was pressed` should appear.):

```
(defun my-press-me ()
  (interactive)
  (message "I was pressed"))

(push '(:propertize "PRESSME"
                    local-map
                    (keymap
                     (mode-line .
                                (keymap
                                 (down-mouse-1 . my-press-me)))))
      mode-line-format)
```

Interestingly, when I press `C-h k` and click in the `PRESSME` text, it reports `my-press-me` both in a GUI Emacs and when running in the terminal.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC this is a bug in Emacs's C code which was fixed recently in Emacs's `master` branch (i.e. it will be fixed in Emacs-27, but not Emacs-26).

There might be a way to workaround the bug with some fancy hack in xterm-mouse-mode in Emacs<27, but I'm not sure it's worth the effort to try and come up with it.

See https://debbugs.gnu.org/29104 for details.

Comment: Amazing! I was testing is against the master branch, but apparently it was a couple of weeks too old... (And it isn't the first time I've stumbled on ancient bugs only find them just fixed.) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce this with Emacs 24.4 under Linux. I have a solution, but I don't claim to understand why it works. Although `describe-key` reads a `down-mouse-1` event when you press the button, pressing the button actually triggers the binding for `mouse-1`. This works both in a terminal (with `xterm-mouse-mode`) and in an X11 window:

```
(push '(:propertize "PRESSME"
                    local-map
                    (keymap
                     (mode-line .
                                (keymap
                                 (mouse-1 . my-press-me)))))
      mode-line-format)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work on macOS running Terminal.app.