# Powerline mode-line menues in terminal mode

Tags: terminal-emacs, mode-line, powerline

When inside terminal mode (`emacs -nw`) I can open the menu using M-F10 in terminal mode. Is there a similar possibility for the powerline `mode-line`  menue on the bottom of the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37259/local-keymap-in-mode-line-doesnt-work-in-terminal): I had to

1. recompile the latest emacs master
2. enable xterm-mouse-mode